# Spring security, i need to handle CredentialsExpiredException but it doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-security

i'm using spring 3.2.0 and spring security 3.1.2 and i set up my webapp (spring mvc) security with a custom `AuthenticationProvider` and a `ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler` to proper handle the `Authentication` status.

The custom `AuthenticationProvider` is perfectly working and 
`throws CredentialsExpiredException` that is correctly mapped at startup (i checked it debugging during webapp starup) and i check that the `ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler` is correctly set up; during debugging, when the `CredentialsExpiredException` has thrown the debugger stops at `onAuthenticationFailure` method but in this method the exception managed ins't the `CredentialsExpiredException` thrown but is a `UsernameNotFoundException` so i can't get work the credendial expired path.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I solved myself, i removed

```
<beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login/login.jsp?login_error=1"/>
```

and now the proper exception is handled